# Is there a difference between putting .lower() in one place or another?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm unsure if it matters where I put .lower() in Python 3.x in the below examples.

I'm wondering if there's a difference (e.g. efficiency or speed) between:

```
bob = input("Are you Bob? Yes or no? ").lower()
if bob == "yes":
    print("Hi, Bob.")
else:
    print("Sorry, wrong person.")
```

and:

```
bob = input("Are you Bob? Yes or no? ")
if bob.lower() == "yes":
    print("Hi, Bob.")
else:
    print("Sorry, wrong person.")
```

I understand that in the second, the variable `bob` isn't affected, whereas in the first, it is, but I'm wondering about any other differences, such as speed/efficiency.

Comment: If there are any performance differences, they should be negligible compared to the time it takes the user to answer the question.

Comment: I believe they call this pre-mature optimization. You've already spent more time thinking about this and typing your question than you will ever save. It is the same operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module to look at the corresponding bytecode.

```
from dis import dis

def case1():
    bob = input("Are you Bob? Yes or no? ").lower()
    if bob == "yes":
        print("Hi, Bob.")
    else:
        print("Sorry, wrong person.")

def case2():
    bob = input("Are you Bob? Yes or no? ")
    if bob.lower() == "yes":
        print("Hi, Bob.")
    else:
        print("Sorry, wrong person.")
```

For the first function:

```
>>> dis(case1)
  4           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (input)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Are you Bob? Yes or no? ')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 LOAD_ATTR                1 (lower)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             15 STORE_FAST               0 (bob)

  5          18 LOAD_FAST                0 (bob)
             21 LOAD_CONST               2 ('yes')
# and so on...
```

For the second function:

```
>>> dis(case2)
 11           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (input)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Are you Bob? Yes or no? ')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (bob)

 12          12 LOAD_FAST                0 (bob)
             15 LOAD_ATTR                1 (lower)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             21 LOAD_CONST               2 ('yes')
# and so on...
```

The same instructions are executed, but in slightly different order, so the two functions should be equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

It's the same code doing the same thing, so there's no significant difference.

The choice of which to use mostly boils down to how you're using `bob`. If you use it in multiple places, always as lowercase, it makes sense to convert it once rather than convert it every time you use it.

On the other hand, if you need both the lowercase version and the actual version entered by the user, it makes sense to convert it to lowercase only when you need it to be lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Its the same operation, being performed on a different line. It makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if things are faster, `%timeit` is a good way in `iPython`

```
#bob = input("Are you Bob? Yes or no? ").lower()
def bob_1():
    bob = "Yes".lower()
    if bob == "yes":
        print("Hi, Bob.")
    else:
        print("Sorry, wrong person.")
def bob_2():
    bob = "Yes"
    if bob.lower() == "yes":
        print("Hi, Bob.")
    else:
        print("Sorry, wrong person.")

%timeit bob_1
%timeit bob_2

#10000000 loops, best of 3: 42.9 ns per loop
#10000000 loops, best of 3: 41.6 ns per loop
```

but to answer your question, they are the same `:)`